# how to open the Dialog editor in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dialog

I have created a simple project that started with the dialog editor to add controls to the form. I closed the dialog editor and I cannot figure out how to show the dialog editor again to add more controls.

How to open the Dialog editor in visual studio 2010?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 3):

Press CTRL+SHIFT+E to open the Resource View window, then expand the folder 'Dialog' and you will see your dialog there and you can double click it to open your dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu bar, try

> > View >> Toolbars >> Dialog Editor