# How to open dialog editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

While working on a GUI C# .net project, I want to edit the dialog it displays.  However, I cannot find a way to open the dialog editor nor find any edit option which might do so.  The `.sln` file was created by an electronic component company (FTDI) and may be downloaded from <s>[here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-I2C.htm).</s> (Hmmm, I need to find correct link.)

I have [enabled the toolbar for dialog editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351695/how-to-open-the-dialog-editor-in-visual-studio-2010).  (No difference.)

When I reverse-click on the "Form" element of the resource view, I would expect the menu to say "edit dialog" or something similar.  Here's what I see:
[image]
Choosing "Go To Definition" displays a C# declaration (`partial class Form1 : Form`).  I want to graphically edit the dialog to rearrange some controls and add new elements.

### Update:

---- Using solution explorer ---

Here is what I see in the solution explorer:
[image]

### Second update

`MPSSE Sensor Demo.Designed.cs` starts with:

```
namespace SensorDemo
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        ... (300+ more lines of boring declaration of UI elements)
```

`MPSSE Sensor Demo.cs` contains mostly application logic beginning with:

```
// #define FT232H                // Enable only one of these defines depending on your device type
#define FT2232H
// #define FT4232H
//######################################################
// This code is provided as an example only and is not supported or guaranteed by FTDI
// It is the responsibility of the designer of the system incorporating any part of this code to ensure correct
// ... blah blah blah

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FTD2XX_NET;
using System.Threading;

namespace SensorDemo
{

    class myFTDI : FTDI
.... (2100+ more lines of logic with occasional assignments to UI elements)
```

Comment: You should right-click 2 levels higher. But it has the wrong icon. Does that Form inherit from Form? Try adding `:Form` after `public partial class Something`

Comment: @ThomasWeller:  You mean on the `MPSSE Sensor Demo.cs` entry?  Doen't seem any  better.

Comment: @ThomasWeller:  well, it already has `public partial class Form1 : Form {` ...   Do you mean to add another ` : Form`?

Comment: No, once is enough. It seems I'm unable to help you.

Comment: @ThomasWeller:  Thanks for trying.  Maybe your answer is of use for a similar problem.

Comment: the icon on Form1 says that it just a class. You can't open visual editor on class

Comment: @AntonSemenov:  Oh, that's subtle.  And totally miss-able by a novice.

Comment: @AntonSemenov: it inherits from Form and has a .Designer.cs file and a RESX file. What else would be needed to make it visually editable?

Comment: @ThomasWeller it seems that you a right. But I still confusing about form icon of `MPSSE_SENSOR_Demo.cs` file. it's not unusual

Comment: @wallyk what happened when you are double clicking on `MPSSE_SENSOR_Demo.cs file`?

Comment: @AntonSemenov:  It jumps to line 3 of `MpSSE Sensor Demo.Dsigner.cs` which has `partial class Form1 {`...

Comment: @wallyk strange. Could you show a code?

Comment: @AntonSemenov:  Sure, which code?

Comment: @wallyk MpSSE Sensor Demo.cs and MpSSE Sensor Demo.Dsigner.cs files

Comment: @AntonSemenov:  I have added the first bits of that code.

Comment: @wallyk I think the problem might be in `MPSSE Sensor Demo.cs` it should contain another part of `partial class Form1`. If such exists try to move it in on top of the file and reload solution. If this won't help, I have no other ideas. Its always bad to have your code in WinForms designer files, cause its not friendly to file modigfications